# Reading \n as really Feed Line character from text file in C

Tags: c, fgets, getline

I'm trying to read text file with C. Text file is a simple language file which works in embeded device and **EACH LINE** of file has a **ENUM** on code side. Here is a simple part of my file :

SAMPLE FROM TEXT FILE :

```
 OPERATION SUCCESS!
 OPERATION FAILED!\nRETRY COUNT : %d
```

ENUM :

```
   typedef enum
   {
    ...
           MESSAGE_VALID_OP,
           MESSAGE_INVALID_OP_WITH_RETRY_COUNT
    ...
   }
```

Load Strings :

```
typedef struct
{
    char *str;
} Message;

int iTotalMessageCount = 1012;

void vLoadLanguageStrings()
{
    FILE *xStringList;
    char * tmp_line_message[256];
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    int message_index = 0;

    xStringList = fopen("/home/change/strings.bin", "r");

    if (xStringList == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    mMessages = (Message *) malloc(iTotalMessageCount * sizeof(Message));

    while ((read = fgets(tmp_line_message, 256, xStringList)) != -1 && message_index < iTotalMessageCount)
        {
            mMessages[message_index].str = (char *) malloc(strlen(tmp_line_message));
            memcpy(mMessages[message_index].str, tmp_line_message, strlen(tmp_line_message) -1);
            message_index++;
    }

    fclose(xStringList);
}
```

As you se in the Sample from text file i have to use **\n** Feed Line character on some of my lines. After all, i read file successfuly. But if i try to call my text which has feed line \n, feed line character just printed on device screen as \ & n characters.

I already try with `getline(...)` method. How can i handle \n character without raising the complexity and read file line by line.

Comment: First of all the function fgets returns a pointer and not a numeric value!

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

Comment: Thats not the problem. I already try lots of things and it is the return of getline method. Dont consider that... Please focus the main problem...

Comment: I mean If i try to use 'OPERATION FAILED!\nRETRY COUNT : %d' for show message on my screen...

Comment: In C, the `\n` sequence in a string literal that appears in your code is interpreted by the compiler as a *single character*, namely, the line feed character. When you are reading it as a string from the file using `getline` or `fgets`, it's read as *two characters*, \ and `n`. You might have to post-process each line you read to translate the sequences. It would be a simple function and wouldn't add that much complexity.

Comment: the function: `fgets()` returns a `char*` not any number, including not -1.    so the code is basically wrong,  Suggest reading and understanding the man pages for the system functions used.  Note: `read` is a well known system function name.   the statement: `while ((read = fgets(tmp_line_message, 256, xStringList)) != -1 && message_index < iTotalMessageCount)` would be better written as: `while ( fgets( tmp_line_message, 256, xStringList)  && message_index < iTotalMessageCount)`  however,  should check the `message_index` before reading another line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As you se in the Sample from text file i have to use \n Feed Line
>   character on some of my lines.

No, I don't see that.  Or at least, I don't see you *doing* that.  The two-character sequence `\n` is significant primarily to the C *compiler*; it has no inherent special significance in data files, whether those files are consumed by a C program or not.

Indeed, if the system recognizes line feeds as line terminators, then by definition, it is impossible to embed a literal line feed in a physical line.  What it looks like you are trying to do is to *encode* line feeds as the "\n" character sequence.  That's fine, but it's quite a different thing from embedding a line feed character itself.

> But after all, i read file successfuly.
>   But if i try to call my text which has feed line \n, feed line
>   character just printed on device screen as \ & n characters.

Of course.  Those are the characters you read in (*not* a line feed), so if you write them back out then you reproduce them.  If you are encoding line feeds via that character sequence, then your program must *de*code that sequence if you want it to output literal line feeds in its place.

> I already try with getline(...) method. How can i handle \n character
>   without raising the complexity and read file line by line.

You need to process each line read to decode the \n sequences in it.  I would write a function for that.  Any way around, however, your program will be more complex, because the current version simply doesn't do all the things it needs to do.

Comment: So i already feel there isnt a way to use \n from a text file directly. Must need a function like decodeFeedLines for each line. Than thanks for answers